# Is BASIC related to Visual Basic?

Tags: relation, basic

I've been reading quite a lot about retro computing and a language stood out: BASIC.

So I would like to know:

- Is Visual Basic related to BASIC?

They sure dont look alike syntax-wise.

Comment: They're related, but a lot has changed over the decades.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC#Visual_Basic

Comment: VB is a superset of the original BASIC, adding additiona keywords and features to support forms, ojbect orientated programming, exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginner's All-Purpose Symbolic Instruction Code (BASIC) is a language invented in the 1964 (you can imagine the kinds of computers that were around in those days) which has evolved thoughout the years.

In some of those generations, BASIC had a syntax quite similar to Visual Basic.

Microsoft loved to add the term "Visual" to languages which have the support for the GUI: Visual Basic, Visual C++, Visual C#, etc.